Use Google Material Icons in Vuetify 3 outside a module
I'm working on an existing code base that creates a Vue app within the page. We are attempting to update to Vuetify 3, but for some reason we're not having any luck getting Google Material Icons to show up in Vuetify elements.
Here is an example: https://codepen.io/TheMissingBit/pen/BaXoyWy
As you can see, I have material icons showing up properly inside of a span, but as soon as I try to specify the same icon inside of a <v-text-field>, the icon is displayed as blank.
I have checked the documentation on the Vuetify website, but it's all focused on modules, which our code base does not have (and we're not looking to redo the whole thing at this point). Can anyone point me in the right direction to set the proper iconset?
